# Number of constraints in convex model

Tags: cvxpy, mosek

Why does a convex QCQP model written using cvxpy and solved using Mosek show more constraints than those defined in the model (As reported by Mosek)?

I notice the same even for cvxpy atom like square(x), where if x is a single variable and constraint:

```
cvxpy.square(x) <= 1
```

shows that the model has 4 constraints instead of just one?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can easily analyze it yourself. Run:

```
import cvxpy as cp

# Construct the problem.
x = cp.Variable(1)
constraints = [cp.square(x)<=1]
objective = cp.Minimize(0)
prob = cp.Problem(objective, constraints)

prob.solve(solver=cp.MOSEK, verbose=True, save_file="dump.opf")
```

and then take a look at the file dump.opf. You will see how cvxpy reformulated the problem in conic form using the quadratic cone to model the quadratic constraint. Essentially it becomes:

```
(x1+1)^2 >= (x1-1)^2 + 4x0^2
x1 <= 1
```

but some auxiliary variables have to be added to input this in MOSEK format.

The MOSEK documentation https://www.mosek.com/documentation/ will have details if something is not clear from the opf file.